# Custom JavaScript not executed from browser

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added a custom js file and enqueued it in my child theme functions.php file. If I declare a variable to test and console.log it from the file itself it works. However, if I try to do the same test from the browser console I get a Reference Error. I tried loading the script file in the footer instead of the header but the problem persists. Any idea what could be wrong?

Enqueue js file from functions.php

```
    function enque_custom_script() {
        if( is_page(146) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'login-tabs', './js/login-tabs.js', array('jquery'), '',true);
        }
      }
      
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enque_custom_script');
```

JavaScript Test  (Login page variable is logged in the console successfully. I get a Reference error if I try to call it again from the browser console)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    const loginPage = document.getElementById('customer_login');

    if (loginPage) {
        console.log(loginPage);
    }

});
```

Comment: try `const loginPage = document.getElementById('customer_login'); if (loginPage) {console.log(loginPage);}` in browser console, does it work?

Comment: It works but returns undefined

Comment: It might just be a problem of scopes. You are defining the loginPage const variable inside the ready function callback. Your browser use the global namespace, the variable will never be there i guess

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you so much.